# Spring cloud kafka stream - Waiting for stream to initialize

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I have 2 Kafka stream and one of the stream is dependent on the other stream. For example,
Stream1 -> Aggregates and create a state store.
Stream2 -> Uses interactive query api to access the state store from Stream 1.

**Problem:** When Stream1 takes longer time to initialize, and Stream2 tries to access the state store I am getting the error "org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException: Cannot get state store term-error-events because the stream thread is PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED, not RUNNING"

**Solution tried so far:** I have added the below retry property for the state store but did not resolve the issue.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.state-store-retry.max-attempts=10
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.state-store-retry.backoff-period=10000
```

I want to find out whether I should change the approach or is there a way to wait for Stream1 to be ready and start Stream2 or any other better way to do this.

**My Code:**

```
// Stream1    
@Bean
    public Consumer<KStream<String, Fallout>> aggregateErrors() {
        return input -> input
                .filter((s, fallout) -> s != null && fallout.getAction() != null && fallout.getAction().equals(Action.ERROR))
                .map((s, fallout) -> {
                    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(fallout.getMessage()) || StringUtils.isEmpty(fallout.getFalloutReasonCode())) {
                        fallout.setFalloutReasonCode("unknown");
                        fallout.setMessage("unknown");
                        return new KeyValue<>(s, fallout);
                    }
                    return new KeyValue<>(s, fallout);
                })
                .groupByKey()
                .aggregate(String::new, (s, fallout, error) ->
                                !StringUtils.isAllEmpty(error)
                                        ? error.concat("|").concat(fallout.getMessage())
                                        : error.concat(fallout.getMessage()),
                        Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("term-error-events")
                                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String()).
                                withValueSerde(Serdes.String())
                );
    }

// Stream 2    
@Bean
    public BiFunction<KStream<String, PracLeftGroupInputRequest>, KStream<String, RequestComplete>, KStream<String, RequestComplete>> joinTermsComplete() {
        return (termsInputRequest, termsRequestComplete) ->
                termsInputRequest
                        .join(termsRequestComplete, this::termsCompleteJoiner,
                                JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(JOIN_WINDOW_MINUTES)), StreamJoined.with(Serdes.String(), new TermInputRequestSerde(), new TermRequestCompleteSerde()));
                         
    }

// Where Stream2 queries the store
    private RequestComplete termsCompleteJoiner(PracLeftGroupInputRequest termsInputRequest, RequestComplete termsRequestComplete) {
        if (termsRequestComplete != null && !StringUtils.isEmpty(termsRequestComplete.getStatus())
                && termsRequestComplete.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("Complete")) {
            final String errorEvent =
                    interactiveQueryService.getQueryableStore("term-error-events", QueryableStoreTypes.<String, String>keyValueStore()).get(termsInputRequest.computeKafkaKey());
            termsRequestComplete.setErrors(ErrorUtil.getTerminationErrorList(errorEvent));

            if (termsRequestComplete.getErrors() != null && !termsRequestComplete.getErrors().isEmpty()) {
                termsRequestComplete.setStatus(CompleteStatus.FAILURE.toString());
            } else {
                termsRequestComplete.setStatus(CompleteStatus.SUCCESS.toString());
            }

            return termsRequestComplete;

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Spring Cloud Version: 2020.0.2
spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams Version: 3.1.2

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of errors are you receiving when you added those two properties? Those properties should retry connecting to the state store. I see that you wait 10 seconds between each try for a max of 10 seconds. Could it be the case that your first stream takes more than 100 seconds to be ready? If that is the case, you might want to increase those values.

Comment: Hi @sobychacko No errors with retry properties. But I see in debug it tried 1s. I also noticed when I start the stream with incorrect store name then retry works. 
`
DEBUG o.s.r.s.RetryTemplate [joinTermsComplete-StreamThread-1] Retry: count=0
ERROR o.a.k.s.p.i.TaskManager [joinTermsComplete-StreamThread-1] stream-thread [joinTermsComplete-StreamThread-1] Failed to process stream task 0_1 due to the following error:
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException: Cannot get state store term-error-events because the stream thread is PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED, not RUNNING
`

Comment: It would be nice if we can reproduce what you see on our end. In any case, could you set a breakpoint on this line and debug it? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/streams/InteractiveQueryService.java#L104 That should give us an indication of what's going on when it tries to connect to the state store while waiting for the first stream to be available.